# Rss parsing in .NET Core

Tags: c#, rss, dnx

Is there anything in .NET Core to support RSS parsing?
Is there any library ready to overtake role of System.ServiceModel.Syndication from .NET 4.6?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this has not been ported yet.

But RSS is pretty basic XML. I guess you can just rewrite the parsing code on your own using XDocument or XmlSerializer.

[This solution](http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/simplified-csharp-atom-and-rss-feed-parser/) looks quite good. It has been there before they introduced the System.ServiceModel.Syndication namespace. (I haven't tested it)